# hreflang tags for Europe

Tags: html, internationalization, hreflang

I'd always understood that, because there is no `en-EU` IETF tag, to target Europe I'd have to either use `en` or list out an `hreflang` for each country within Europe.

Looking at the source of [Think With Google](https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/intl/en-gb/), I noticed the following:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="//thinkwithgoogle.com/intl/es-419/" hreflang="es-419" />
```

Which appears to use a UN M.49 code to indicate *Spanish for the Latin America and Caribbean region*.

The [UN M.49 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M.49) also lists a code for Europe - `150`.

Does it follow that I could have the following `hreflang` tag to indicate English for the European market?

```
<link rel="alternate" href="//example.com/intl/en-150/" hreflang="en-150" />
```

Comment: The google docs for hreflang makes no reference to IETF but it does reference ISO-639 and IS0-3166. By this definition en-eu could be considered valid.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to specify languages for each European country just set hreflang="en". If you are going to specify English for each European country be aware that only IE (Ireland), MT (Malta) and GB (Great Britain) have English as their official language.

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate your thoughts but my question was around the possibility of using M.49 format, as per 'Think with Google'

Comment: I can test it on my site if you'd like google will send me back an error in a day or two if it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay it isn't throwing an error on google webmaster's tools. I went looking for information on it and supposedly support for UN M.49 was added in 2009 with rfc 5646 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5646. Which I found by looking through w3.org https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/

Answer (score 2):

In the [Google docs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) it states the hreflang format consists of XX-YY where:

- XX is [ISO_639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)
- YY is [ISO_3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

By this it is conceivable that "en-eu" is actually correct as [ISO_3166-1 #EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#EU) is noted as being "reserved on request of [ISO 4217/MA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) for the European monetary unit Euro" which dating back to 1998. It specifically lists "eu" code relating to the ".eu" top level domain.

Most of the talk on the net around "en-eu" seems to be option rather than evidence based or direct from Google.

It would be worth running some experiments on "en-eu". I have also asked for more details on this in the Google doc as they specifically show examples for GBP and USD but ignore Euro.

Based on above "en-eu" make the most sense if reserved codes are considered valid to Google Bot.

Answer (score 1):

As per W3, you can use the region subtags as listed in the UN M.49 region code. So the tag `hreflang="en150"` is as valid.

The document also states

> Only one region subtag can appear in a language tag, and it must appear after the language subtag

So you can't then use `en-053`(Oceania) together with `en-150`(Europe)

And since the [IANA Language Subtag Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry) lists 150, you can use it as any other region tag.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/#region

Comment: Should be `hreflang="en-150"`. Indeed valid.